# JHipster - awesome font gone after downgrade

Tags: angular, html, jhipster

I had to downgrade jHipster because the new version (5.x) apparently doesn't support elasticsearch anymore.

So I deleted my application, re-generated it with JHipster 4.14.0 and added my components again.

Now, all the awesome font icons are gone. I did run npm install to make sure nodejs is correctly loaded again, but it did't help.

Here's an example on how I use font-awesome:

```
 <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active" 
[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/" (click)="collapseNavbar()">
        <span>
            <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span jhiTranslate="global.menu.home">Home</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I also replaced the vendor.ts with a working version from another app generate with JHipster 4.14.0, that also didn't help.

Do I need to take any additional steps?

Comment: Important Info: I left the original navbar intact, meaning, I'm currently using the generated version, not the backed up version.

Comment: Elasticsearch is supported in v5, and in v5.3.x the embedded Elasticsearch feature was added back (it now uses `spring-data-jest`).  Also the font-awesome imports and format changed between the versions so you should look how it's used in the generated code and match that

Comment: Yes, I noticed the format change, that's why I left the newly generated (4.14.0) navrbar version intact, since the "old" way was generated again. And there lies the problem. Somehow my versioning seems to be wrecked and I coulnd't get elastic search running within my project...

Comment: Just FYI, elastic search indeed seems to work with 5.3.x,  but the elastic search reindexer doesn't work with that version. It's really annoying.

Comment: This is the error: 

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: It's normal as the reindexer has not been updated to use spring-data-jest, it's a good opportunity to contribute to https://github.com/geraldhumphries/generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer

Comment: Thanks for the input. Any way I can reindex the elastic search index? Just saving the record using the repo on startup didn't help either....

Comment: Anyway, elastic search has many problem within jhipster 5.3.x. Even normal search terms in the generated front end won't work as the jest calls only return errors when calling findAll(). 

So i have to downgrade, it's a bit frustrating to be honest...